# How to install IDAPython a python plugin for IDA on windows 10

Tags: python, ida

I am really stuck. I have been searching materials(videos/documents) that help me to install python plugin on IDA. I tried this https://github.com/idapython/src/ and followed the installation process but still IDA is unable to find python as plugin.

I am using IDA freeware and latest version of python on windows 10.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need IDA python installed. It's already installed for you.

E.g. on OS X the path is following:

```
ls -1 /Applications/IDA\ Pro\ 7.1/ida.app/Contents/MacOS/python
PyQt5
ida_allins.py
ida_allins.pyc
ida_auto.py
ida_auto.pyc
ida_bytes.py
ida_bytes.pyc
...
```

But in your case you should know that IDA Free has no idapython included...

Comment: Ok but I am using windows 10 and how can I incude idapython in IDA free on windows.

Comment: You can't because free version is limited.

Comment: Thank You. Will you please let me know if any similar software available so that I can integrate python to it.

Comment: @sachinrathod https://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/home/radare2-python-scripting/